# NSJSONSerialization-header in front JSONData

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization

I am using NSJSONSerialization Class to parse the following JSON data, however, it returns me null. I have header in front of my JSONData, "jsonp1343930692(". Is there any way I could handle it / eliminate it before putting into NSJSONSerialization?

```
     jsonp1343930692("snapshot":[{"timestamp":1349143800,"data":[{"label_id":10,"lat":29.7161,"lng":-95.3906,"attr":{"ozone_level":37,"exp":"IN","gridpoint":"29.72:-95.39"}},{"label_id":10,"lat":30.168456,"lng":-95.50448}]}]})
```

I am also putting my code here just give snapshot:

```
(void) httpRequest
{
url1=[NSURL URLWithString: url];
_weak ASIHTTPRequest *request1=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url1];
[request1 setCompletionBlock:^{
   requestData=[request1 responseData];
   [self parsing];

 }];

}

(void) parsing
{
    NSError myError =nil;
    NSDictionary *dic=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestData     options:NSJSONMutableLeaves error:&myError];

NSLog(@"%@",dic);

}
```

Comment: Is there an alternate endpoint or method call on the service that returns JSON and not JSONP?

Comment: Hello sir, unfortunately, I could not get your point. could u please elaborate your answer?

Comment: This link explains the differences between JSON and JSONP, it's worth a read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP, In my experience where there's a JSONP call on a server there's generally a JSON call too. The call you're currently making is returning JSONP, you actually want JSON. Solve the problem at the source not at the client!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, and is also guaranteed to stop on the first parenthesis.

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSSccaner scannerWithString:JSONPString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"(" intoString:NULL]; //This gets rid of the jsonpNNNNN
NSString *JSONWrappedInParens = [[scanner string] substringFromIndex:[scanner scanLocation]]; //Now we have our JSON wrapped in parentheses
NSCharacterSet *parens = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"]; //trim the parentheses leaving all internal parens untouched.
NSString *justJSON = [JSONWrappedInParens stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:parens];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: r u kidding me !! wooww. I am testing now!

Comment: I wrote that on the fly should work though, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: it did not pick up JSON data properly, but definetly that is something I should learn ! :-)

Comment: Bummer! :( I wonder what's going wrong? I'll have to try it on your sample data... EDIT: for whatever reason it's not scanning up to the first paren right!

Comment: superrr!!! I just packed up my stuff leaving from school, I will definitely check it once I arrive home thanks a lo Carl, appreciated!!

Comment: You're welcome! I love to spread the word about `NSScanner` it's seriously underrated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving it a shot from the browser so I'm not sure it works

```
-(void) parsing
{
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:requestData
                                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // you gotta extract a valid JSON format
    // this is not very clean code, You need to depend on what your server responds
    // and fail gracefully
    // I'm assuming that your json data will always be between ()
    // NOTE: in your question you're missing a '{' at the begining of your json to be valid
    NSData *data = nil;
    NSRange *range = [responseString rangeOfString:@"("];
    if (range.location != NSNotFound && range.location < responseString.length) {
        responseString = [responseString substringFromIndex:range.location + 1];
        responseString = [responseString substringToIndex:responseString.length -1];
        data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
    if (data) {
        NSError myError =nil;
        NSDictionary *dic=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data     
                                                          options:NSJSONMutableLeaves
                                                            error:&myError];
        if(!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", dic);
        } else {
            //Serialization error
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    } else {
        //something went wrong with json data extraction
        // fail gracefully
    }
}
```